# Rad Studio how to turn off the Zoom buttons on a MapView?

Tags: delphi

I would like to take off the Zoom buttons (+ -) on a MapView  with Rad Studio 10.2

I have tried this code  but does'nt work

**MapView1.ControlOptions := [TMapControlOption.Zoom];**

Does someone could help me :)

Thank's a lot

Comment: Delphi 2010 has no such class. Please tag the question correctly. `MapView1.ControlOptions := [TMapControlOption.Zoom];` says that you want zoom buttons shown. Don't you want `MapView1.ControlOptions := [];`

Comment: Thank's a lot !!!! :) ::)

Answer (score 1):

The [**ControlOptions**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Maps.TCustomMapView.ControlOptions) property is of type [**TMapControlOptions**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Maps.TMapControlOptions) which is a set of certain options. To exclude only one option from it, whilst keeping the rest of the options untouched write this:

```
MapView1.ControlOptions := MapView1.ControlOptions - [TMapControlOption.Zoom];
```

To include a certain option to that property write:

```
MapView1.ControlOptions := MapView1.ControlOptions + [TMapControlOption.Zoom];
```

Comment: Thank's a lot Victoria :)